# How to run Batch Photoshop Script to move layers X amount sequentially?

Tags: batch-file, photoshop

I have 70 layers in a photoshop file. I need to move X vertically, one after the other. So they'd look like:

```
>>Layer 1<<
>>Layer 2<<
>>Layer 3<<
```

Instead of just being stacked on top of each other. Not sure how to do this? Ideally, I should just specify an amount in pixels to Transform up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A layer seems only be able to move with delta.

To move by delta use the `MyLayer.transform(DeltaX,DeltaY);` where MyLayer is a reference to the `artLayer` you want to move. The unit of DeltaX and DeltaY are the same as your Ruler in photoshop.

I wrote this little function to move a layer to an absolute position. I hope this will be of some use to you...

```
//******************************************
// MOVE LAYER TO
// Author: Max Kielland
//
// Moves layer fLayer to the absolute
// position fX,fY. The unit of fX and fY is
// the same as the ruler setting. 

function MoveLayerTo(fLayer,fX,fY) {

  var Position = fLayer.bounds;
  Position[0] = fX - Position[0];
  Position[1] = fY - Position[1];

  fLayer.translate(-Position[0],-Position[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for this! Because of this tip I managed to complete a script that downloads/places (thousands of) map tiles... couldn't have done it without you ; )

I am new to 'Photoscripting' so I'd like to point out something (now obvious) that may also take other newbies than I a while to get: if you've calculated your 'fX' and 'fY' input through some mathematical means, be careful to *explicitly* add the unit you are using to your input number, otherwise you'll be placing things all over the place (waaaaaay off the canvas in my case ; P ).

Like this:

```
 MoveLayerTo(myLayerRef, myX + "px", myY + "px").
```

Thanks a lot again, and cheers!